# Is there a website which lists all the climbs?

Tags: road-bike, road, climbing

I love to ride uphill with my road bike and the longer the climbs are the better. I want to build a "climbs to ride up before I die" list. What websites should I used to build such a list? I'am aware of [strava](https://www.strava.com) but I would like a place that let's me input a country and it then shows all the climbs ranked by distance or elevation gained or some other thing. In strava I can use "segment explore" and it shows some climbs but it also leaves out many. It's only really useful to search climbs in a specific region, not in a whole country.

Comment: Answers that are made up of links to other resources are discouraged here. I think you just need to put some work in with Google Search. Simply googling 'famous cycling climbs' nets some interesting lists. You can also try 'famous cycling climbs in usa' or 'famous cycling climbs in europe' if you want region specific answers.

Answer (score 2):

The site you are looking for is https://www.climbbybike.com/.